# Neural Network in matlab stops after 0 epochs and cuts layer connections

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm experiencing a very strange behaviour in Matlab using the NN toolbox.

I'm building a NN based RL simulation, so I have to train my network repeatedly/calling the train function multiple times (think of a game: after each "move" I observe a reward, so I have a new input->output pair on which I want to train my network).

Every single time I train my network with a single input-output couple, my network will not train anymore, meaning that when I call `net=train(net,newinput,newtarget)` its weights don't change at all.

I had a look into it and I discovered that after the first training my network CUTS the connection between input layer and hidden ones, as well as others. see picture below.

[image]

here is a simple code able to reproduce this behaviour.

```
nnetwork=feedforwardnet([5,5]);
nnetwork.trainFcn = 'traingd';
nnetwork.trainParam.epochs=1; %one episode in RL means one update
nnetwork.trainParam.lr=0.0001;
nnetwork.trainParam.goal=0.1;
nnetwork=train(nnetwork,zeros(43,1),[0]);
view(nnetwork)
```

after this, calling again for example

```
nnetwork=train(nnetwork,zeros(43,1),[0]);
```

doesn't change the network a little bit.
What is going on? if I leave the NN GUI open it tells me ''goal has been reached after 0 iterations''.

all I want to do is something like this:

```
for i=1:100
    x=take_turn()
    t=observe_t()
    network=train(network,x,t)%"update the weights like in Q learning
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the problem? The NN is doing exactly what you want.

You are training a neural network to have output "0" for any input, thus the output does not need to be connected to the input to give the correct answer. The algorithm starts at all zeroes for the weights of the NNs (all zeroes==no connection) and finishes, as it reached its objective with 100% of accuracy, you have **the PERFECT neural network**.

What really happens is that the inner weighs are equal to zero, and as said, this means disconnected path. The GUI is smart and shows you a disconnected path instead of a line. This is the same if the output is always "4", or any other value. The NN does not need the input to determine the output, thus it disconects it.

When you train NN's with different data you get different weights, you just happened to train your NN for a system with `weights=0`.

---

So... The question arises: Do you know what you are doing?
Specifically in this line of code:
`nnetwork=train(nnetwork,zeros(43,1),[0]);`

You are saying "please MATLAB, train a NN with the structure in `nnetwork` so it behaves as following:

- When I input 43 zeroes, I want the output to be zero exactly
- An thats it, I don't want anything more.

And what is your network doing? Exactly that. It is outputting zero, and because you haven't told it what to do when the input is not 43 zeroes, then it does whatever it wants. In this case, output zero too, because its the easiest solution.

However, all in your question hints that you do not want to "train" your network! you want to [`adapt`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/adapt.html) your network, with some online learning!
So check the function `adapt`!

Something like the following (probably you need to change how the input is passed (perhaps `x=[x take_turn()]` ...).

```
for i=1:100
    x=take_turn();
    t=observe_t();
    network=adapt(network,x,t);
end
```

Comment: you are right, now that I see the adapt function it's clear that it is what is intended for RL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem with the training dataset since when I change the dataset to Matlab default dataset `building_dataset` the NN node connection return again without any problem.

```
[X,T] = building_dataset;
nnetwork=feedforwardnet([5,5]);
nnetwork.trainFcn = 'traingd';
nnetwork.trainParam.epochs=1; %one episode in RL means one update
nnetwork.trainParam.lr=0.0001;
nnetwork.trainParam.goal=0.1;
nnetwork=train(nnetwork,X,T);
view(nnetwork)
```

[image]
The bottom line: try to find a proper dataset to train your NN otherwise will get nothing. In addition, what you expect to get by training NN with zeros! I mean the following code `nnetwork=train(nnetwork,zeros(43,1),[0]);`

Comment: more than the dataset I believe it's its unitary dimension. your 1 epoch corresponds to a lot of X-Y pairs, but for RL I have to train on each single X-Y pair, one pair at the time. in 'nnetwork=train(nnetwork,zeros(43,1),[0]);'  zeros is just a random state, I can put there ones(43,1) and still get the cut problem.